# Math Notation for a dictionary in an array

Tags: notation, markov-process

In Python programming, normally an array is considered a vector:

example an array b is defined as:

$b = b_n \in \mathbb{R}^{|N|} =[b_{0}, b_{1},....b_{|N-1|}] $

lets say there is now a vector c

Instead of real numbers in vector c like above, I now have one dictionary in the vector. (I just happen to code it so, changing it now would be problematic)

From what I know dictionary is considered a function that map a parameters to a variable

How do I define vector c like I did vector b ? is it normal to have a function in a vector in math ?

Comment: Hi, welcome to math.SE.  As you say a dictionary can be thought of as a function.  So it's not quite clear to me what you are asking.  If you want it to also be a vector, note that the set of functions $A \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ forms a vector space with the rules $f+g := h$ where where $h$ is defined so that $h(x) = f(x) + g(x)$, and similarly $\alpha f$ is defined so that $(\alpha f)(x) = \alpha f(x)$ for a scalar $\alpha$.  Does that help?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply (Jair Taylor), basically my code looks like: vector c = [(a function)], if we call tht function as function A, then it would look like, vector c = [A]. My question is, if I can just define vector c = [A] ? does it makes mathematical sense doing so ?

Comment: What is the actual python code?

Comment: If you like you could define $c$ to be the set $\{A\}$, does that work?  But from your description it sounds like the fact that it's a singleton set $\{A\}$ instead of just a function $A$ is not so important to the overall algorithm (since you say you just happened to code it so.) If so, there's no reason I can see to model that fact mathematically.

Comment: hi @saulspatz, an example of the python code would be: a python list c, a python dictionary mydict, => c = [  mydict  ] = [  {1:100, 2:200, 3:300, ... }   ]

Comment: hi @jairTaylor. Im inclined to agree with you that it may not make senses in math. But Ive decided to just proceed with defining: c = [ A ] instead, that is until I can find some math equivalent if there is any.

Comment: I don't understand what this is supposed to accomplish.  Instead of accessing $100$ as `mydict[1]` you have to do two accesses: `c[0][1]`

Comment: @saulspatz that's true, but Ive far gone down the coding with these that changing it would leads to a lot of debugging. the original idea was to include this dict as one of the state variable for my MDP model. I just add array(kind of a holder) 1st for all state variables and later fill in each of the arrays with what the state variables are supposed to be. but thts as far as coding is concern. Im wondering about the math notation though.

Answer (score 0):

One question here is how to model Python mathematically.

This is actually somewhat non-trivial because Python allows many features which make this difficult. Consider the following code:

```
x = []
x.append(x)
```

How does one model the resulting `x` mathematically? It is a list that contains itself. Mathematics does allow for this, but it requires an understanding of "corecursion", which is a highly nontrivial topic.

But the issue actually runs even deeper. If we write

```
x = []
y = []
```

then in any "nice" mathematical model, we should expect `x` and `y` to behave identically to one another. But this is not the case at all, since the statements `x.append(1)` and `y.append(1)` have completely different behaviour.

The nature of Python means that if we wish to model what is going on in Python, we must model the entire state of the program from top to bottom as a single mathematical object. This is quite undesirable and cumbersome.

Another question is: what is the mathematical equivalent of a dictionary?

In set-based mathematics, it is possible to define a "sequence" as a function, the domain of which is $\{0, 1, ..., n - 1\}$ for some $n$ (possibly including $n = 0$). This is the mathematical equivalent of a "list" or "tuple" from Python.

More generally, one can define a "dictionary" as a function whose domain is finite. Clearly, sequences are a special case of "dictionaries" in mathematics. Generally, mathematicians have little use for "dictionaries" (and don't call them dictionaries), preferring to simply work with functions in general.

Note that the "values" of a sequence or a dictionary can be anything at all under this definition. It is quite normal in mathematics to work with sequences of all kinds of things. One speaks of sequences of sets, sequences of numbers, sequences of functions, sequences of sequences, etc.

Comment: I do agree with you, that it is difficult to formulate  python mathematically, although this is the first time Ive encountered such problem personally. But your example also seems to highlight the issue as well